# How to implement live video streaming in a website using VLC

Tags: html, jsp

I am creating a website which play live videos of any event.The Only
way i know is the VLC, is there any way to implement faster and smooth
streaming???

Comment: You haven't even explained why VLC isn't sufficient. Of course there are numerous other libraries (gstreamer, darwin streaming server, http streams, etc) but you haven't provided nearly enough information about your requirements to get a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

To generate FLV streaming from VLC reffer this
[link](https://wiki.videolan.org/Flash_Video/)

Now to play FLV streaming using Flow flash player reffer this [link](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/)

Now below is the code for playing video in browser

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
        <a  
             href="http://10.100.200.123:11443"
             style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px"  
             id="player"> 
        </a> 
        <script>
            flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");
        </script>
</body></html>
```